# Translating linux command script to powershell command script

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

i am attempting to translate this snippet:

```
 "find &filsti./ -name '*.sas7bdat' -type f -printf '%u;%p;%a\n'"
```

into powershell, so that i can scan for files the same way in windows as i do in linux. Can anyone assist me? Appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: What is `&filsti./`?

Comment: &filsti is a sas let -> %LET filsti=$BESTAT/forlop/wk14;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what that last part is, but try this:

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path" -Include *.sas7bdat -Recurse